# Add CSS3 or Jquery transitions to slides

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a horizontal slider and I would like to add some effect to in between transitions

What I have now are the slides moving from side to side and images popping up using css3

[image: Current Slide]

I would like to add a transition effect where the images fold to the side when the slide changes

Something like the image bellow

[image: Slide with transition]

Thanks a lot in advance

Edit: Display some code

For the elements I have use the following CSS3

```
#plane {
z-index: 9;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1200px;
    width: 1200px;
    top: 30%;
    max-width: 70%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    -webkit-animation: plane 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation: plane 0.5s forwards;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes plane {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes plane {
    100% { left: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried (aka some code).

Comment: Nice graphics, cool question

Comment: I created something [very similar](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/bxjeI) if you'd like to use it. You could change it to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks Zach, Let me give it a shot. This looks pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

Use [3D transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) with [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZ3t7/)

```
#plane {
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
}
#container {
    perspective: 2000px;
}
```

Comment: Cool is this Mozilla only??